# Is it possible to pre-populate subject field in mail when sharing a URL

Tags: ios, ios7, rubymotion

In my app the users can click a share button which shows all the possible installed applications that are capable of sending a `NSURL`. When the user clicks `Mail` I want to repopulate the subject field (I'm already populating the body, which is working). Additionally when the user clicks `SMS` then I want to have a different message than when the user clicked `Mail`

Is this possible to do?

This is what I'm doing currently but not sure how to customize the message for `Mail` vs. `SMS`

```
  activity_vc = UIActivityViewController.alloc.initWithActivityItems(["Check it out!",
  NSURL.URLWithString("http://myurl.com/?id="+@item_id.to_s)], applicationActivities:nil)
  activity_vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical
  activity_vc.excludedActivityTypes = [
    UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList,
    UIActivityTypeAirDrop,
    UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard,
    UIActivityTypePrint
  ]
  @delegate.presentViewController(activity_vc, animated:true, completion:nil)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this using `setValue(forKey:)`

```
activity_vc.setValue('Populated subject field', forKey: 'subject')
```